# Different extents of SOC and BDOD VRT files

Tags: soilgrids

I downloaded the SoilGrids layers from the WebDAV and reprojected them to EPSG:4326 using the following command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of VRT ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5.vrt ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5_4326.vrt

Subsequently, I used GDAL to translate the VRT files to GeoTiffs:
gdal_translate -of GTIFF -a_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5_4326.vrt ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5_4326.tif

This worked out all fine, but I realised that SOC and BDOD are shifted by almost a whole pixel. Because I applied the mentioned GDAL commands to all files equally, I am sure that it must be an issue with the initial files. I went back and checked the VRTs and realised that the longitudinal extents of SOC and BDOD are three pixels smaller than all the other VRTs. This seems to have produced my issue.
Is this something you want to correct? Or can you suggest another workaround, so that all layers are projected equally?

Comment: You could try this: a) check the pixel size of one of the vrt files that you have now and b) re-run gdalwarp by using this pixel size in `-tr` and by adding `-tap`. There should be no need to assign srs with gdal_translate because gdalwarp has set it already into VRT.

Comment: I also believe that all layers are projected equally but some layers have different pixel sizes and therefore reprojected pixels do not match exactly. That may be a problem for some analysis. Using "target aligned pixels" may fix this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange, if you have not done so, please take some time to check the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Additional notes to your question: internally these maps are already in GeoTIFF format, so it doesn't make much sense to convert the VRT to GeoTIFF. Also bare in mind the distortions introduced by the Marinus projection, and how it expands the map by at least 40%. That projection is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gdalinfo` it is easy to verify that indeed the extents are slightly different:

```
$ gdalinfo nitrogen_15-30cm_Q0.5.vrt
[...]
Upper Left  (-19949750.000, 8361000.000) 
Lower Left  (-19949750.000,-6147500.000) 
Upper Right (19861750.000, 8361000.000) 
Lower Right (19861750.000,-6147500.000)
```

```
$ gdalinfo soc_60-100cm_Q0.5.vrt
[...]
Upper Left  (-19949000.000, 8361000.000) 
Lower Left  (-19949000.000,-6147500.000) 
Upper Right (19861750.000, 8361000.000) 
Lower Right (19861750.000,-6147500.000)
```

The SOC map has 3 fewer raster cells, i.e. it is 750 metres narrower. The covariates selected by the model are different between properties, and thus the slight difference. However, there is no shift, all cells in these maps align exactly. If you observe a shift it is possibly a consequence of the cartographic projection you are using.

As alluded in the comments, by employing the `-tr` and `-te` arguments to `gdalwarp` you can make sure all the outputs align to your requirements.