# Soilgrids layers should but don't all have the same CRS

Tags: soilgrids

I am working with SoilGrids layers downloaded from their file repository (https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/). I was trying to stack the layers, but found that, in addition to different extents (see [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362986/different-extents-of-soc-and-bdod-vrt-files)), layers also use two different coordinate reference systems (CRS). I am using R to process the raster files.

While most layers give:

```
> library(raster)
> crs(raster("sand_0-5cm_mean.tif"))
CRS arguments:
 +proj=igh +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Toward the beginning of the `.vrt` file I used to build the geoTIFF, I see

```
<SRS>PROJCS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",GEOGCS["GCS_unnamed ellipse",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["Unknown",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"],UNIT["Meter",1]]</SRS>
```

That CRS is used for most layers I used. However, a few (so far `nitrogen_0-5cm_mean.tif`, `phh2o_0-5cm_mean.tif` and `soc_0-5cm_mean.tif`) use another crs:

```
> crs(raster("nitrogen_0-5cm_mean.tif"))
CRS arguments:
 +proj=goode +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Again, the `.vrt` files have

```
<SRS>PROJCS["World_Goode_Homolosine_Land",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9102"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Goode_Homolosine",AUTHORITY["Esri","43059"]],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100001"]],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100002"]],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100010"]],PARAMETER["Option",1.0,AUTHORITY["Esri","100036"]],UNIT["Meter",1.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["Esri","54052"]]</SRS>
```

When I plot the maps however, the projections seem identical. From what I found in [this PDF from PROJ](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/proj.4/gh-pages/proj.pdf) (proj.org seems down at the moment), `+proj=goode` is used for the uninterrupted Goode Homolosine projection. However, SoilGrids layers are supposed to all use Interrupted Goode Homolosine which would be `+proj=igh`. For now, I am just changing the CRS with:

```
> nitrogen0_5 <- raster("nitrogen_0-5cm_mean.tif")
> sand0_5 <- raster("sand_0-5cm_mean.tif")
> crs(nitrogen0_5) <- crs(sand0_5)
> writeRaster(nitrogen0_5, "nitrogen_0-5cm_mean_fixedcrs.tif")
```

That seems to work, but I would rather only change the crs if I am really sure about which one it is. Is it on purpose that the crs differ between raster files or is that an error?

Answer (score 1):

All SoilGrids maps are created and served with the same CRS, as explained [in the FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_the_Homolosine_projection). This can be easily verified using `gdalinfo` against the original map:

```
$ gdalinfo nitrogen_0-5cm_mean.vrt
[...]
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984 ellipse",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (-19949750.000000000000000,8361000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (250.000000000000000,-250.000000000000000)
[...]
```

The map you are using is not one of the original served by ISRIC. There is no file named `sand_0-5cm_mean.tif` in the [WedDAV service](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids). You are advised to obtain the maps directly from that service (or through [WCS](https://maps.isric.org)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the problem and it's not related to the Soilgrids maps. The VRT files had been changed after downloading them without me knowing. My issue is therefore specific to this case and AFAIC my question can be deleted.